# a question about inheritance of Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

```
function ClassA()  
{  
    this.a=[];
    this.aa=100;  
}  


function ClassB()  
{  
    this.b=function(){return "classbb"};  
}  
ClassB.prototype=new ClassA();  
Array.prototype= new ClassB();  
var array1= new Array();
alert(array1.b());
```

Why can't Array  inherit ClassA and ClassB? Thanks.

Comment: I hope we both agree that this question is of theoretical nature, since Array would be rendered useless if you overwrote its prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not quite the way to make the Array.prototype inherit from your objects. It would overwrite `Array.prototype`, which isn't allowed obviously.

You can however *extend* the prototype of Array with the properties/methods of ClassA/ClassB like this:

```
function ClassA() {  
  this.a=[];
  this.aa=100;  
}  

function ClassB() {  
  this.b=function(){return "classbb"};  
}

ClassB.prototype = new ClassA; 

var instB = new ClassB;
for (var l in instB){
    Array.prototype[l] = instB[l];
}

var array1 = [];
alert(array1.aa);
```

You can also:

```
Array.prototype.classb = new ClassB;
var array1 = [];
alert(array1.classb.aa);
```

Comment: Can I write it this way?  function ClassA() {  
  this.a=[];
  this.aa=100;  
}  

function ClassB() {  
  this.b=function(){return "classbb"};  
}

ClassB.prototype = new ClassA; 


for (var l in ClassB.prototype){
    Array.prototype[l] = ClassB.[l];
}

var array1 = [];
alert(array1.b);

Comment: Not really. First, you'll need to assign `Classb.prototype[l]` (which you are enumerating in a for loop). Second, if you do so, you will miss `ClassB.b`, because that's not in ClassB's prototype. It would work if you added method b to ClassB's prototype. See http://jsfiddle.net/pgw9q/

Comment: Could you tell me why it still doesn't work if I write it this way:function ClassA() { this.a=[]; this.aa=100; }
function ClassB() {  }

ClassB.prototype = new ClassA;
ClassB.prototype.b=function(){return "classbb"};

for (var l in ClassB.prototype){
   // console.log(l);
    Array.prototype[l] = ClassB.[l]; //I delete prototype here
}
var array1 = [];
alert(array1.b());

Comment: `ClassB.[l]` should be `ClassB.prototype[l]`. What do you mean with "*I delete prototype here*"? Nothing is deleted in your code.

Comment: Why can't ClassB.prototype[l] be replaced by ClassB[l]? I am new in javascript. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Better ignorant then arrogant, I say. Some links that may give you more insight in prototypal inheritance: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming, http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/prototypal_inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

[The standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) prohibits overwriting `Array.prototype`:

> The initial value of Array.prototype
>   is the Array prototype object
>   (15.4.4).
>   This property has the
>   attributes { [[Writable]]: false,
>   [[Enumerable]]: false,
>   [[Configurable]]: false }.

You can easily verify that browsers comply to this:

```
var origArrayProto = Array.prototype;
Array.prototype = new function () {}; // try to overwrite
alert(Array.prototype == origArrayProto); // true
```